# Bootstrap contents moves over affix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have created a navbar using `div tag` which contain `4 tabs`.

I have used an `affix concept` on this navbar. Note my application page is divided in to three parts using `row` class - the left and right part of the page is empty using `col-lg-2` class and on middle of the page, I am trying to show the contents under `col-lg-8` class. Every content of my page comes under the `col-lg-8` class.

```
        <div class="row" style="background-color:#4C97C8;" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="150">
            <div class="btn col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="color:white;height:30px" ng-click="jump(1)" ng-mouseenter="hovering=true" ng-mouseleave="hovering=false" ng-class="{'clicked': hovering}">
            <strong>ABOUT</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="btn col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="color:white;height:30px" ng-click="jump(2)" ng-mouseenter="hovering2=true" ng-mouseleave="hovering2=false" ng-class="{'clicked': hovering2}">
            <strong>FEATURE REQUEST</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="btn col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="color:white;height:30px" ng-click="jump(3)" ng-mouseenter="hovering1=true" ng-mouseleave="hovering1=false" ng-class="{'clicked': hovering1}">
            <strong>PRODUCT</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="btn col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 bg-primary" style="color:white;height:30px">
            <strong>PRODUCT LINE</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css is-

```
.affix {
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
}

.affix + .container-fluid {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

The problem is - other contents like buttons, accordion panel moves over this navbar. Another one is - when affix effect take place, the navbar comes out of col-lg-8 class in larger screen size.

What is the problem?
jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/shashankg/707n3r21/

Comment: could you please create a fiddle including your problem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `z-index: 10;` to your affix-css like i did here:

```
.affix {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

this should solve your problem :)

Working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/707n3r21/3/

> if you want to learn more about z-index you should take a look at this
>   documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

---

**// EDIT :**

To solve your other problem change the width of your affix-css to `66.66666667%`. Thats the same width like the width of col-lg-8 (bootsrap.css)

```
.affix {
  top: 0;
  width: 66.66666667%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/707n3r21/4/

---

**// EDIT:**

For smaller screens add this to your css:

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .affix {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Now we should have fixed it all:
https://jsfiddle.net/707n3r21/10/

Comment: thank you. it solved my first problem but not other. Other problem is-when affix effect take place, the navbar comes out of col-lg-8 class in larger screen size?

Comment: whats the other problem? :)

Comment: Use bigger screen col-lg and just drag down the scrollbar. The navbar width exceeds the screen layout. Got it?

Comment: edited my answer, take a look at it ;) please mark the answer as the right answer, if i solved your problems :)

Comment: you solved the problem in larger screen but in smaller screen it exist. Pls can you help?

Comment: fixed, take a look at it ;)